# Json file to rest api in spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I have a json file with array of objects, i want to read it and create rest api with couple GET methods. What are best practices to do so? Should i create in memory database (H2), save json objects there and then do the rest? I am looking for most efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is static and you’re just doing GET requests, in your data layer you can just read from the contents of the file into POJOs. Then if you need to get more sophisticated you can always change up the implementation detail to H2 or some other DB.

Answer (score 1):

If you JSON file is small and does not change frequently, you do not need to put it in H2 or another database. Just read the JSON file from the disk once and use it in your REST API endpoints.

`Jackson` is a good library for [processing JSON data in Spring Boot](https://attacomsian.com/blog/processing-json-spring-boot). It offers multiple options to read and consume the JSON data.

Comment: Thank you for answer, ill follow your advice. I saw someone using H2 database for same thing but with xlsx file. Do you mind explaining when it is a good idea to use database?

Comment: Here is a good read: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/190482